# Delete but keep x amount of rows per input

Tags: postgresql, delete

Let's say I have the following table, with data:

| Id | User | Item | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Banana | D+1 |
| 2 | 1 | Banana | D+2 |
| 3 | 1 | Banana | D+3 |
| 4 | 2 | Apple | D+1 |
| 5 | 1 | Apple | D+2 |
| 6 | 2 | Apple | D+3 |
| 7 | 2 | Apple | D+4 |

The column definitions are: `UUID (pk)`, `UUID`, `TEXT`, `TIMESTAMPTZ` respectively. None of the columns allow nulls.

New rows are added frequently, so I've decided I need a cleanup job to run on a schedule. (Done via my application code)

In order to not keep too much data, I've decided I want to keep the latest 2 entries, per user and item. I guess there could be, in rare cases, time duplicates. If so, any one of the two items should be removed.

My intended result should look like:

| Id | User | Item | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | Banana | D+2 |
| 3 | 1 | Banana | D+3 |
| 5 | 1 | Apple | D+2 |
| 6 | 2 | Apple | D+3 |
| 7 | 2 | Apple | D+4 |

I'm not sure how to accomplish this delete query.

Answer (score 3):

Sample data:

```
create table user_items (
    user_items_id serial primary key,
    user_id uuid,
    item_name text,
    purchase_time timestamptz
);

insert into user_items (user_id, item_name, purchase_time)
values ('7f89114c-04df-4a80-afe1-f79e819470de', 'Banana', '2022-01-01'),
    ('7f89114c-04df-4a80-afe1-f79e819470de', 'Banana', '2022-01-02'),
    ('7f89114c-04df-4a80-afe1-f79e819470de', 'Banana', '2022-01-03'),
    ('8d0f7f91-2e3b-49e9-b81f-0e800f9a967b', 'Apple', '2022-01-01'),
    ('7f89114c-04df-4a80-afe1-f79e819470de', 'Apple', '2022-01-02'),
    ('8d0f7f91-2e3b-49e9-b81f-0e800f9a967b', 'Apple', '2022-01-03'),
    ('8d0f7f91-2e3b-49e9-b81f-0e800f9a967b', 'Apple', '2022-01-04');
```

Since some users may only have 1 item and some of them may need to be kept (since even if it's just 1 it's still part of the "last 2 items"), I have edited my solution to work in a different manner.

The following query will delete the corresponding rows and leaving only the last 2 (or less) entries partitioned by user and item. This will also delete one of 2 duplicates should they exist.

```
delete from user_items
where user_items_id in (
    select x.user_items_id
    from (
        select
            row_number() over(partition by ui.user_id, ui.item_name order by ui.purchase_time desc) as rn,
            ui.user_items_id
        from user_items ui
    ) x
    where x.rn > 2
);
```

Running a select statement on the table after running this delete will show the following:

| user_items_id | user_id | item_name | purchase_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 7f89114c-04df-4a80-afe1-f79e819470de | Banana | 2022-01-02 00:00:00.000000 +00:00 |
| 3 | 7f89114c-04df-4a80-afe1-f79e819470de | Banana | 2022-01-03 00:00:00.000000 +00:00 |
| 5 | 7f89114c-04df-4a80-afe1-f79e819470de | Apple | 2022-01-02 00:00:00.000000 +00:00 |
| 6 | 8d0f7f91-2e3b-49e9-b81f-0e800f9a967b | Apple | 2022-01-03 00:00:00.000000 +00:00 |
| 7 | 8d0f7f91-2e3b-49e9-b81f-0e800f9a967b | Apple | 2022-01-04 00:00:00.000000 +00:00 |

You may change the filter to `x.rn > 1` to delete everything except the last entry (so keeping only 1 entry instead of 2)

You may also use this solution to achieve the same result of keeping the last entry only:

```
delete from user_items
where user_items_id not in (
    select distinct on (f.user_id, item_name)
        f.user_items_id
    from user_items f
    order by user_id, item_name, purchase_time desc
);
```

Which would return the following after deletion:

| user_items_id | user_id | item_name | purchase_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 7f89114c-04df-4a80-afe1-f79e819470de | Banana | 2022-01-03 00:00:00.000000 +00:00 |
| 5 | 7f89114c-04df-4a80-afe1-f79e819470de | Apple | 2022-01-02 00:00:00.000000 +00:00 |
| 7 | 8d0f7f91-2e3b-49e9-b81f-0e800f9a967b | Apple | 2022-01-04 00:00:00.000000 +00:00 |

Answer (score 2):

Copy the rows to be retained to a working table. Truncate the original table. Copy back the retained rows.

This may be faster if a relatively small fraction of existing rows are retained as truncation does not require subsequent vacuuming.

Comment: Very interesting solution, never thought about that